# Fix Decimal Point in Javascript (Using Range Slider)

Tags: javascript

```js
    var slider = document.getElementById("pSliderRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("SliderPrice");
    var slots = document.getElementById("NumberOfSlots");
    slots.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value
    output.innerHTML = slider.value / 1.5;

    // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
    slider.oninput = function() {
      slots.innerHTML = this.value;
      output.innerHTML = this.value / 1.5;
    }
```

```html
<input type="range" min="3" max="60" value="2" class="p-slider" id="pSliderRange">
<p class="normal-text">Total Slots : <span id="NumberOfSlots"></span></p>
            <p class="normal-text">Monthly Price : $<span class="normal-text" id="SliderPrice"></span></p>
```

Hello,
I've made a price counter with Range Slider.
It counts the price according to Slots. It simply divides the number of slots with 1.5
The only problem I am facing is the decimal point. Is there any way to limit the decimal points? I searched many forums but didn't get the answer (maybe) because I am using the slider to count value.
Any help would be highly appreciate :)
Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output.innerHTML = (this.value / 1.5).toFixed(2);
```

this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toPresicion`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Number/toPrecision

or `toFixed`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

examples:

```
var value = 1.234;
console.log(value.toFixed(2)); // result: '1.23'
console.log(value.toPrecision(3)); // result: '1.23'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toFixed(x) to keep x numbers of decimals

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("pSliderRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("SliderPrice");
    var slots = document.getElementById("NumberOfSlots");
    slots.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value
    output.innerHTML = slider.value / 1.5;

    // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
    slider.oninput = function() {
      slots.innerHTML = this.value;
      output.innerHTML = (this.value / 1.5).toFixed(2);
    }
```

```html
<input type="range" min="3" max="60" value="2" class="p-slider" id="pSliderRange">
<p class="normal-text">Total Slots : <span id="NumberOfSlots"></span></p>
            <p class="normal-text">Monthly Price : $<span class="normal-text" id="SliderPrice"></span></p>
```